# LocalStorage Problemas al Recargar la Pagina

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy Trabajando con `localStorage` ,mi problema es cuando actualizo la pagina para verificar si los datos no se borra y después agrego un nuevo registro, los datos de la tabla que he registrado anteriormente se reemplaza con el nuevo registro.Desearía que me ayudaran en esto porfavor

**Función Guardar**

```
let agregar = [];
const Enviar = document.getElementById("Formulario");


const GuardarDatos = () => {
   
    let nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value;
    let apellido = document.getElementById("Apellido").value;
    let correo = document.getElementById("Correo").value;
    let usuario = document.getElementById("Usuario").value;
    let contraseña = document.getElementById("Contraseña").value;
    const Datos = {
        nombre,
        apellido,
        correo,
        usuario,
        contraseña
    }  
    agregar.push(Datos);
    console.log(agregar)
    localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(agregar))
    listar();
}
```

**Función Listar**

```
let listar=function(){
    let  arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        destroy:true,
        data:arrayLista,
        columns:[
           {"defaultContent":"<td>#</td> " },
           {data : "nombre"},
           {data : "apellido"},
           {data : "correo"},
           {data : "usuario"},
           {data : "contraseña"},
           {"defaultContent":"<buttom class='btn btn-success'>#</buttom> <buttom class='btn btn-danger'>#</buttom>" }
           
        ]
    } );
} ;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listar);
```

**Evento Enviar**

```
 Enviar.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        GuardarDatos();
        Enviar.reset();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>


    
    <div class="container m-auto" style="width: 800px;">
        <h3 class="title mt-5">
            <i class="material-icons">
                account_balance
            </i>
               <u><i>Formulario de Usuarios</i></u> 
        </h3>
         <form id="Formulario" style="margin-left: 45px;"> 
            <div class="row my-3">
                <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                    <label for="Codigo">Codigo:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Codigo" placeholder="Ingresar Codigo">
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" placeholder="Ingresar Nombres  ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="Apellido">Apellido :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Apellido" placeholder="Ingresar  Aplellidos ">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-8">
                        <label for="Direccion">Correo :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Correo" placeholder="Ingresar Correo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row my-3">
                    <div class="col-sm col-md-8">
                        <label for="Usuario">Usuario :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Usuario" placeholder="Ingresar Usuario">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="row my-3">
                  <div class="col-sm col-md-8">
                      <label for="Password">Contraseña :</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Contraseña" placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña">
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </form> 

      
        <div id="ListaClientes" class="mt-4">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Contraseña</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
               <!-- <tbody id="table"></tbody>  -->

             

                
            </table>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
  </body>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <!--DataTable JQuery-->
    
     <script src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un arreglo llamado `agregar` el cual se declara `let agregar = [];` y el único valor que contiene es el que se le agrega en la función `guardar()` con el código `agregar.push(Datos);`, luego se inserta al localStorage.

El arreglo `agregar` debe tener los datos que se recuperaron del localStorage para que pueda concatenar los nuevo y sobre escribirlos.

En la función `listar()` se lee el localStorage y los datos se guardan en la variable `arrayLista`, lo que se debe hacer después es asignar ese arreglo al arreglo `agregar` para que los nuevos elementos se agreguen a los anteriores.

```
let  arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
     agregar = arrayLista;
```